# What is the recommended way of encoding/decoding XDR types in erlang?

Tags: erlang, network-programming, externalinterface

In another SO discussion, we were talking about interfacing an erlang application to another non-erlang app that is using [XDR encoded packets for network communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation).

Unfortunately, I couldn't really find any real pointers on dealing with XDR data using erlang.

So what is the recommended way of dealing with XDR encoded data in erlang?

Thanks

PS: So far, I could find the following resources:

- [Getting Erlang to talk to the outside world](http://www.erlang.se/workshop/2002/Armstrong.pdf) (2002, PDF, only mentions XDR shortly)
- [Sendmail Meets Erlang: Experiences Using Erlang for Email Applications](http://www.jetcafe.org/~npc/doc/euc00-sendmail.html) (2000, also nothing relevant in here, but still an interesting read)
- [And then there's this posting](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2000-August/001543.html), which is relevant and provides some XDR routines, but is from 08/2000, and so even predates erlang's support for the bits syntax.

Comment: +1. Currently learning Erlang. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [rpc](https://github.com/gebi/jungerl/tree/master/lib/rpc/src) in the [Jungerl](http://jungerl.sourceforge.net/) Erlang source collection. It has a code-generator that produces Erlang code to manage XDR-based protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Building your own XDR encode and decode library isn't difficult.

Encoding Erlang terms to XDR is trivial:

```
%% @spec push_bool(bool()) -> binary()

push_bool(Value) ->
    case Value of
        true ->
           <<0, 0, 0, 1>>;
        false ->
            <<0, 0, 0, 0>>
    end.
```

Going the other way is a bit more verbose, depending on how you would like error reporting to be done.  I've chosen exceptions:

```
%% @spec pull_bool(binary()) -> {bool(), binary()}

pull_bool(Bin) ->
    {Value, Tail} = 
        try
            <<0, 0, 0, V, T/binary>> = Bin,
            {V, T}
        catch 
            error:{badmatch, _} -> 
                throw({xdr_error, "Invalid boolean value"})
        end,
    Result = case Value of
                 0 -> false;
                 1 -> true;
                 _ -> throw({xdr_error, "Invalid boolean value"})
             end, 
    {Result, Tail}.
```

There really aren't that many XDR data types in total so it would maybe be a couple of hundred lines of code in total.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as mentioned in the original posting, I am aware of the complexity, and there is a full implementation of an XDR library available from 2000: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2000-August/001543.html I was just asking about the recommended/standard way of doing this reliably today.